# Dynamic Content and Infowindow-Size & -Position

Tags: carto, carto-js, infowindow

I have to display Dynamic Content (aka embeds … tweets, youtube-videos, facebook-posts etc.) inside a Infowindow … now how can I make sure to ***resize* and *position*** the infowindow properly so the following will not happen:

Pic 1: This is perfect … (but has no embeds…)

Pic 2: … and this not so much. Because of the embeded Content the Infowindow gets resized to the bottom … the «arrow» or the Infowindow-«Bottom» should be @ the height where you can spot «Rapp» on the map

How can I achieve that the infowindow gets resized (more height to top, not to bottom), so it stays positioned correctly.

[image: This is perfect …]
[image: … and this not so much. The Infowindow gets resized to the bottom … the arrow or the infowindow-bottom should be in the height where you can spot «Rapp» on the map]

Comment: Have you altered maxHeight? http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#attributes

Comment: @AndyEschbacher No, I don't have any `width` or `maxHeight` inside my js-declaration … but CSS — but only a `min-height`